# How do I center this button using HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have no experience coding html or css other than the few lessons I did on Code Academy but the company I work at has tasked me with fixing our abandoned cart email. The only way I can fix it is by adjusting the html and css and I am a little lost. I am trying to figure out how to center a button using an older form of css (it was the template provided)

the code that was on the template for the buttons

```
                            <table class="row">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="column">
                                        <table class="complete-order">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>
                                                    <p>
                                                        <a href="{{notification.checkout_link}}" target="_blank">
                                                            {{lang 'complete_order'}}
                                                        </a>
                                                    </p>
                                                </th>

                                                <th class="expander"></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The solution someone gave in the comments was to use this code below, but I don't think I put it in the right place because it separated the entire email in half... lol.

```
<table class="complete-order">
<tr>
<td>
<p>
To complete your order right now, just click on link below.
</p>
<p>
<a href="#">Complete Order</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Could someone please help me center this button?

Comment: Please post actual code in your question, not pictures.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.complete-order{text-align:center;}
.complete-order a{
background-color:#8cb84a;
border:none;
border-radius:4px;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:#fff;
display:inline-block;
font-weight:600;
padding:8px 32px;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;
text-decoration:none;

}
```

```html
<table class="complete-order">
<tr>
<td>
<p>
To complete your order right now, just click on link below.
</p>
<p>
<a href="#">Complete Order</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can centre your table with class row. If there are not other CSS in the head of the email to overwrite this then it should work perfectly.

Change:

```
<table class="row">
```

to:

```
<table align="center" class="row">
```